# What is reservoir computing in simple terms, and how can it be used with quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, classical-computing, computational-models

For those who are familiar with the notion of Reservoir Computing, can you explain the concept with simple terms and how it can be used with quantum computing ?

Comment: this is quite broad. Can you clarify what you find unclear about the topic from the many available sources online (eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_computing)?

Comment: I don't understand why it's working and how it can be used in Quantum Machine Learning

Comment: that's still very vague. You might want to have a look at reviews such as https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.11831. Questions on the topic are potentially interesting, but it's hard to give meaningful answers unless the question is sufficiently specific. Otherwise the answer would just be a review of the topic, of which there's plenty around